# Conducting viewshed with building heights using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, viewshed, visibility, offset

I am seeking to conduct a viewshed (using ArcGIS visibility - spatial analyst) of from an observer point, which is a human standing on a hill. Once I have added the single input point, I have added 1.7m to the Observer Offset to represent the human. I want to understand what the observer can see in the surrounding landscape. Clearly the DTM that is my input raster will account for this. However, I am totally baffled as to how I can incorporate the height of a single building into this analysis. e.g. within the landscape there is one building, with a height of 12metres. I would like to know if this building is visible, along with everything else in the topography represented by the DTM. I had read that I should use OFFSET B for this purpose, and so I added an OFFSET B field and 12m value to the relevant point in the attribute table of a *different* feature class to represent  the building.

When I try to run the analysis I get error:

> Error 001000  Surface offset: Field OFFSETB does not exist.

This led me to think that the observer point and building need to be in the same attribute table as the observer point, but when I did this and applied OFFSET B value to the building, it simply conducted a second viewshed using the building as an observer point. I assume this is because it had two observer points.

I am therefore confused as to how I can add the height of the building to be included in the viewshed. Perhaps I need to add a definition query to the attribute table to select ONLY the observer point. And, then only my observer point is used for the viewshed, but the viewshed  also takes account of the building height as it is specified in the offset B field, even though 'filtered out' for the analysis? But as I understand it applying a query will remove the building from the analysis. So, my problem is: if OFFSET B is what I need for the building height, where does this field go - where is the data drawn from? Perhaps I need to simply add a field in the attribute table for height, but what would I call it to ensure it is considered?

Comment: Sorry not an answer, I've always found this confusing and have never had to use the viewshed tool for anything complex. A workaround is to add the height of the building to the DEM at the building location (preferably a polygon but a point will do at a pinch). i.e add a height field to a building poly featureclass, calc the height value = 12,  convert building poly to raster using height field with cell size, extent and snap raster = DEM. Use raster calculator `Con(IsNull("building_raster"), "DEM", "DEM" + "building_raster")` to create new DEM.

Comment: Many thanks will try

Comment: Your OFFSETB field. How have you spelt it? In your question you mention OFFSET B, check if you are using OFFSETB (no spaces).